# Tree filtering performance

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

Currently I have a structure that looks like:

Name,Type, RefName, RefType

The goal is that the user selects an element and a direction and then get a treestructure in a webpage (JSON data) that displays all elements matching his criteria. As you can imagine, going up is not hard. The tree structure gets narrower and thus performance is no issue. While going down more and more nodes get added and at a certain point it gets slow. At this moment the nodes are added to a HashSet and I go recursively trough them. My program structure for going down is:

```
    private void BuildChildNodes(ElementRefItem element, int goalDepth, int currentDepth =0) 
    {
        if (goalDepth <= currentDepth)
        {
            return;
        }

        currentDepth++;
        var elements = refElementRepository.All().Where(x => x.ElementName == element.Name);
        foreach (var refElement in elements)
        {
            var node = CreateNode(refElement.ElementRefName, refElement.ElementRefType);
            BuildChildNodes(node, goalDepth, currentDepth);
            element.ChildNodes.Add(node);
        }

    }
```

I am looking for tips to optimize this part of the code. Are there other ways of doing this faster?

(Actual data structure is a bit more complex, but for clarity it is easier to show this version)

Comment: Hierarchical data type usually have `Children` property (instead of `RefName` and `RefType` as in your case) to reference children. Then you don't need that linq query running over **whole** collection for every child.

Comment: In your description you mention that you want to display all elements matching some sort of "Criteria". What's that Criteria? In the code I see that you're looking for all elements with the same name as the root element - is that's the criteria you're talking about? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Arnon Basically its just going up and down. Only further down the road there is also some context property that I have to match to nodes earlier. But the concept stays the same.

Comment: What is `refElementRepository`? Is it a sequential list? A tree? A `HashSet`? I suspect your performance problem is in the selection, as you appear to be searching the entire repository for each child node. Also, the `All()` in your LINQ expression is unnecessary. You can write `refElement.Where(...)`, and it will do the same thing. (Note that this is an aesthetic consideration only, as the extra `All()` there doesn't impact performance.)

Comment: The repository is a custom resository that gives back a HashSet. The All is actually returning the HashSet because I implemented it to return the HashSet (so removing it would not be very helpful).

Comment: @Patrick - Can you explain the meaning of the line: `var elements = refElementRepository.All().Where(x => x.ElementName == element.Name);`? It seems that there's lies your performance problem, but I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do there? **Why are you comparing every element's name in the repository to the root element's?** Can there be more than 1 element with the same name? It looks like you intend to iterate over the **children** of the current element, but you're iterating on the query results instead...

Comment: refelementRepo.All() gives back a HashSet of parent child relations. It is a non db repository. All dat ais in memory. So I select a node, then fetch the childnode and after I fetched those I retrieve the childs of these nodes etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of performing a query every time I retrieve the data once (all data is refreshed once a day) and I build two HashSets; one for parent-child relations and one for child-parent relations. This makes it possible to find an element in the HashTable (witch is very fast) and therefor retrieving the whole tree part. In meta code it looks like this:

```
- Create new cache (bottom up, top down)
- Foreach CachedObject
- Check if items exist (both parent and child)
     : yes -> select node
     : no -> create node and insert it in the new cache
 - add child to parent node
```

This gives a hashset of Parent objects. Now you can select a parent object and automagically you get your whole tree section.